# Can you use googlemock to set expectations on function that does not belong to a class?

Tags: c++, googlemock

If in my main I have a function, func, that is called from main, can I use googlemock to say EXPECT_CALL(**no_class_here**, func).Times(1)?

**no_class_here** would be something like the scope operator to indicate that it doesn't belong to a class, ::. I don't know how that would work, but in the function implementation

I don't want to put func inside of a class when it is just a static function and does not require a class in order to run...

Should I just give up and put everything I'm going to test in a class all the time? I know that JUnit and JMock, everything is a class in java, so there's no choice, but I guess that the ability to descend from a class with nothing but virtual functions is probably the mechanism that allows googlemock to do its work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid not.  In googlemock's documentation relating to [mocking free functions](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/V1_6_CookBook#Mocking_Free_Functions), they show how to replace a free function with an equivalent function in an interface class.

It's up to you whether you think it's worth changing existing code purely to allow testing.  I probably wouldn't do that generally, particularly in this case where you'd be changing a non-member function to a member-function.